# github home page wont load properly and incomplete

Tags: github

[image]
it happens every now and then on chrome.No problem whatsover on mozilla.whats going on?

Comment: https://www.githubstatus.com/ if that's true it seems all systems are healthy. Could be your connection being slow, or their status page is not reflecting that.

Comment: This does not look like a programming-related issue